# Bootstrap carousel not working

Tags: carousel

During development it works fine while I check it on local host, but when I uploaded it on to the server it doesn't work. Can't find the issue, could someone please look into my code :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="row">

                    <div class="daug">
                    <div id="daugia" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                      <!-- Indicators -->
                      <h1> ATLIKTI DARBAI </h1>
                      <h3> NUOTEKŲ ŠALINIMO INŽINERINIŲ SISTEMŲ REMONTAS DAUGIABUTYJE VILNIUJE </h3>
                      <p>Šiame objekte teko įgyvendinti užsakovo užduotį –<br></br> pakeisti viso buto nuotekų šalinimo inžinerines sistemas.<br></br> Kadangi senos statybos buto nuotekų šalinimo vamzdžiai neatitiko užsakovo poreikių,<br></br> paskaičiavome ir pakeitėme į naujus. </p>
                      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#daugia" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#daugia" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#daugia" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        <li data-target="#daugia" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                        <li data-target="#daugia" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                        <li data-target="#daugia" data-slide-to="5"></li>
                        <li data-target="#daugia" data-slide-to="6"></li>
                        <li data-target="#daugia" data-slide-to="7"></li>

                      </ol>

                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                      <div class="item active">
                        <img width="700" height="394" src="../images/portfolio/daugiabutis/daug1.jpg" alt="daugia">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                          Situacijos nuotrauka 1
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="item">
                        <img width="700" height="394" src="../images/portfolio/daugiabutis/daug2.jpg" alt="daugia">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                          Situacijos nuotrauka 2
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="item">
                        <img width="700" height="394" src="../images/portfolio/daugiabutis/daug3.jpg" alt="daugia">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                          Situacijos nuotrauka 3
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="item">
                        <img width="700" height="394" src="../images/portfolio/daugiabutis/daug4.jpg" alt="daugia">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                          Situacijos nuotrauka 4
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="item">
                        <img width="700" height="394" src="../images/portfolio/daugiabutis/daug7.jpg" alt="daugia">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                          Situacijos nuotrauka 5
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="item">
                        <img width="700" height="394" src="../images/portfolio/daugiabutis/daug8.jpg" alt="daugia">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                          Situacijos nuotrauka 6
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="item">
                        <img width="700" height="394" src="../images/portfolio/daugiabutis/daug9.jpg" alt="daugia">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                          Situacijos nuotrauka 7
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="item">
                        <img width="700" height="394" src="../images/portfolio/daugiabutis/daug10.jpg" alt="daugia">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                          Situacijos nuotrauka 8
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div >



                      <!-- Controls -->
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#daugia" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Atgal</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#daugia" role="button" data-slide="next">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Kitas</span>
                    </a >
                  </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

Here is the link to the site : www.ftsantechnika.lt

Comment: Is it simply not working or is there an error log?

Comment: Well I don't understand why, because I use the same code for others. If you look in the site i specified, it would be more clear. The first one doesnt work at all and others after that with the same code work just fine, and the last one doesnt work also, though i used the same code.

Comment: But on localhost it works perfectly fine. Can't understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that I specified src path wrongly, plus some of the files were not in lowercase in my original documents. Thank you for your help.